# Difference between the ELF vs MAP file

Tags: linker, embedded, elf

The linker can output both the ELF and the MAP file. These files are especially relevant in the embedded systems world because the ELF file is usually used to read out the addresses of variables or functions. Additionally, the ELF file is used by different embedded measurement or analysis tools.

When I open a MAP file, then within it, I can see for each global variable and every external function the following information: allocated address, symbolic name, allocated bytes, memory unit, and memory section.

On the other hand, once I open the ELF file, it is a binary file and not human readable. However, some tools I use are able to read it out and interpret it. Those tools can interpret the ELF file, and obtain the information about the symbolic name of a variable/function and its address or even show a function prototype.

From my understanding the ELF and MAP files are basically containing the same information, it is just that the first one is binary and the latter one is the text file.
So what are the actual differences between these two files from the content perspective?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Clifford That is a good point. However, while posing a question "thinking loudly" with extra information may make the question longer, on the other hand it can also lead to additional conclusions made by the person who is asking. And therefore this might lead to a more precise final question.

Comment: OK, it might.  It certainly led me to address the apparent misconception rather then just the the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The primary output of the linker (i.e. its main purpose) is to produce the fully linked executable code.  That is the ELF (Executable Linkable Format) file.  An ELF file may as you have observed contain symbols - these are used for debug.  It may also contain meta-data that associates the machine code with the source code from which it was generated.  But the bulk of its content (and the part that is not optional) is the executable machine code and data objects that are your application.

The MAP file is an optional *information only* human readable output that contains information about the location and size of code and data objects in your application. The MAP file includes a summary that shows the total size and memory usage of your code.

In an embedded cross-development environment, the symbol information in the ELF file is used when the code is loaded into a source-level symbolic debugger.  The debugger takes the binary code/data segments in the ELF file and loads them onto the target (typically using a JTAG or other debug/programming hardware tool), it loads the symbols and source-level debug meta-data into the debugger, then while the real machine code is executing on the target, that execution is reflected in the debugger in the original source code where you can view, step and break-point the code at the source level.

In short, the ELF file is your program.  The MAP file is, as its name suggests, a map of your executable - it tells you where things are in the executable.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Nonetheless, I have one remark. You wrote about ELF file: '"It may also contain meta-data that associates the machine code with the source code from which it was generated.". From my limited understanding the meta-data actually associates the machine code with assembly code? At least that is my impression, because the tool I use can reconstruct a call graph of an application that includes assembly instructions for each function in the graph. Only after you load the source files, is the tool able in addition to the assembly also show the app source code. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @SimpleThings the meta data includes line number information that relates to the source code. Machine code to assembly code association is implicit in the symbol table because there is a direct relationship between an assembly instruction and a machine code instruction.  The tool you are referring to is generating a disassembly (machine code to assembly).  The compiler can generate assembly code from the source if you ask it.  Some compilers do that as an intermediate step, then assemble it.  If you generate an assembly listing from the source, it is likely that the listing will have the line

Comment: I tried to read out one ELF file using readELF tool. Its Symbol Table contains fields such as _Address_, _Symbol_ _name_, _Size_, _Type_ (OBJ, FUNC, SECTION), _Bind_ (LOCAL, GLOBAL), etc. But I do not understand how can one reconstruct the original application code / assembly from this? I could not find mentioned _direct relationship between an assembly instruction and a machine code instruction_.

Comment: @SimpleThings ReadElf clearly does not present all the content of the elf file, it's output is meta-data. To see the code in any kind of readable format you need a disassembler. You cannot reproduce the source code from the object code.  That would be like trying to reconstruct a tree from toilet paper.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you cannot reconstruct the source code from the binary code without additional information nor I was saying this in my last statement. Would your sentence also mean that an ELF file contains **only** the binary code of the original application? Would this also imply that when a debugger is stepping through a code, then it has to reconstruct, i.e dissasemble as you said earlier,.the original application through the meta-data which is also stored in the ELF file?

Comment: @SimpleThings No, not eve _with_ additional information. It is a one way process.  We are getting off topic here, you should post a new question if you are interested in what an elf file contains, or how a debugger works.  The debugger does not have to disassemble the code, but it can for presentation if you choose a disassembly view.  Assembler is just a human-readable presentation of machine code. The debugger knows the register values and the memory content, and references that back to the source via metadata in the object (elf) file.

Comment: To be clear you said _"I do not understand how can one reconstruct the original application code / assembly from this?"_ - forgive me if that sounded to me like you thought you could reconstruct the code form the ELF file, but that seems the obvious interpretation.  The debug information in the elf file includes the path to the source code, the debugger reads the debug data and loads the source - it does not "reconstruct" anything.  Typically if the source is not available, a debugger will present a disassembly (a direct assembler mnemonic representat6ion of the machine code).

Comment: the disassembly is directly generatable from the binary using objdump. objdump is a superset of what readelf can do.